# I Use Google Cloud Platform for host website and for send mail I use google spreadsheet but after send mail how redirect to my website?

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, html-email, google-sheets-api, contact-form

"https://www.thecloudconsult.com/" website is hosted on google cloud platform. It has one contact form. For sending mail I'm trying mail() function, SMTP, Mailgun but it is not working in Google Cloud Platform.

Then I tried Google Spreadsheet for send mail using google app script generate script for mail sending. I receive mail but I got message from script

> This application was created by another user, not by Google.

Script code:

```
var REDIRECT_URL = "https://www.thecloudconsult.com/";
function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
    record_data(e);
    
    // shorter name for form data
    var mailData = e.parameters;

    // names and order of form elements (if set)
    var orderParameter = e.parameters.formDataNameOrder;
    var dataOrder;
    if (orderParameter) {
      dataOrder = JSON.parse(orderParameter);
    }
    
    // determine recepient of the email
    // if you have your email uncommented above, it uses that `TO_ADDRESS`
    // otherwise, it defaults to the email provided by the form's data attribute
    var sendEmailTo = (typeof TO_ADDRESS !== "undefined") ? TO_ADDRESS : mailData.formGoogleSendEmail;
    
    // send email if to address is set
    if (sendEmailTo) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: String(sendEmailTo),
        subject: "Contact form submitted",
        // replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form actually collecting a field named `email`
        htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData, dataOrder)
      });
    }

   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput( "<script>window.location.assign=\"" + REDIRECT_URL + "\";</script>");
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}
```

When mail send successfully after redirect in "https://www.thecloudconsult.com/" website for this I use below code

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput( "<script>window.location.assign=\"" + REDIRECT_URL + "\";</script>");
```

At that time I got message from script and redirection is not working.

> This application was created by another user, not by Google

How solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script remove warning banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635284/google-apps-script-remove-warning-banner)

Comment: No Its not answer of my question.

Comment: I don't know how, but I wouldn't do it this way. You can't send mail via SMTP from GCP, so it's not surprising that didn't work. But you can use a 3rd party service like SendGrid or Mailjet, which is the generally recommended approach. These are pay services, but at least for Sendgrid you can have a free plan for up to 12K emails/month.